# coding drag drop images on web page

Tags: vb.net

About a month ago, I got some wonderful help from Idle_Mind in developing a visual basic desktop application whereby children could drag & drop images (pictureboxes) in the correct order.  I've displayed the code that Idle_Mind provided below.  It works beautifully and is enjoyed by the students.

Now, I'm trying to recreate the application on a web site.  I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.   Using the same code in the "Code Behind" creates lots of errors.  It appears that Image controls don't have the same drag/drop properties.

Should I be trying to create these drag/drop behaviors from Visual Basic in the "code behind" or should I be trying to accomplish this with html?  The Visual Web Developer uses Visual Basic.net and XHTML 1.0 Transitional (I believe)

As always, Thanks!

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Source As PictureBox = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each PB As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
            PB.AllowDrop = True
            AddHandler PB.MouseMove, AddressOf PBs_MouseMove
            AddHandler PB.DragEnter, AddressOf PBs_DragEnter
            AddHandler PB.DragDrop, AddressOf PBs_DragDrop
            AddHandler PB.DragOver, AddressOf PBs_DragOver
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        If Not IsNothing(PB.Image) AndAlso e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Source = PB
            PB.DoDragDrop(PB.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
            Else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
            End If
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
            Else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
            End If
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PBs_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        PB.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
        If e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move Then
            If Not (PB Is Source) Then
                Source.Image = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A web application isn't a desktop application, it's a completely different technology stack.  The code-behind in this case is running entirely server-side and can't interact with the user interface in realtime.  You'd want to look into implementing this functionality in JavaScript.  Fortunately, things like drag and drop functionality have widely used plugins to help.  Take a look at the jQuery UI plugins, for example.  Or interact.js, or even just the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop

Comment: @David That might be good for an answer.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: I wasn't sure, since it's not so much an "answer" as a direction to further resources.  But re-reading the question, I guess you're right.  There really isn't any other way to answer it.

Comment: Yes, your answer does give me the direction I should pursue.  That's mainly what I was wanting to know.  With the Visual Web Developer 2008 Express that I have, I'm assuming that if I download one of the Jscript plug-ins, it will give me access to the classes, controls and properties I need to accomplish the drag & drop features I'm after?

Comment: @RicknTruckee: Don't think of it as "classes, controls and properties" in this case.  It's very unlikely that any JavaScript plugin you find is going to give you the same visual designer experience you get in Windows Forms.  I can't stress enough how entirely different the technology stack is.  If you end up using jQuery plugins then you'll likely be operating on DOM elements (HTML elements on the page) and the events on those elements (click, drag, etc.).  This won't be accomplished in a visual form designer, it'll be accomplished by writing JavaScript code.

Comment: I've been doing as David suggested, exploring HTML and JavaScript to accomplish my drag/drop goals on a web page.  Using the below three functions

Answer (score 1):

A web application isn't a desktop application, it's a completely different technology stack.

The code-behind in this case is running entirely server-side and can't interact with the user interface in realtime.  You'd want to look into implementing this functionality in **JavaScript**.

Fortunately, things like drag and drop functionality have widely used plugins to help.  Take a look at the [jQuery UI plugins](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), for example.  Or [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/).  (See the demos on their website for what kind of functionality you'd be looking for.)  Or even just [the MDN documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop).

It's not going to be as simple as copying and pasting code.  But there are a lot of resources to be found online to help you implement the functionality.